# apple sign in is returning 419 error in laravel on callback function

Tags: laravel, csrf-token, sign-in-with-apple, apple-login

I am working on login with apple using laravel framework using refrence [GeneaLabs/laravel-sign-in-with-apple](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-sign-in-with-apple).
I have followed all the steps carefully.after login function when callback function is run by apple it gives me error code 419 i.e. issue of missing csrf token.
So, The apple is hitting callback function without csrf token.

Here is error image :
[click here to see error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llIHy.png)

Comment: Could you please add some [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your routes and related stuff so that we know what we are dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in your web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```